# How to show or hide AGSArcGISMapImageLayer sublayers

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis-runtime

I just upgraded my project from **arcgis runtime 10.2 to 100.2.1** and I was able to run the AGSFeature Layers but **AGSArcGISMapImageLayer** are giving issues

I am just loading the **AGSArcGISMapImageLayer** layer which contain sublayers and getting their data like this

```
let mapServiceInfo = (dynamicMapServiceLayer as? AGSArcGISMapImageLayer).mapServiceInfo
  if let layerInfos = mapServiceInfo?.layerInfos {
     for layerInfo in layerInfos {
       //get the sublayer data
     }
}
```

Now i just was to show and hide the layer according to user requirement

for that **i checked this arcgis link** :- [link to show hide the image layer](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios/blob/master/arcgis-ios-sdk-samples/Layers/Manage%20sublayers/MapImageSublayersVC.swift)

But while getting above data of sublayers using above procedure it is giving **me 10 sublayers data**

but according to the link when I'm using the method

```
dynamicMapServiceLayer.mapImageSublayers.count
```

then **it returns only two objects or sublayers**
Because of this I was not able to implement the show hide functionality

**So how should i use the above mentioned link approach in my case ? or is there any other way to do this ?**

Answer (score 0):

By searching through the api's I found a solution to hide or show the dynamicMap layers(**AGSArcGISMapImageLayer**)

```
**layersHidden** is an array which contain the url of layers which I want to hide from map

let mapServiceInfo = dynamicMapServiceLayer?.mapServiceInfo
let layerInfos = mapServiceInfo?.layerInfos

for layerInfo in layerInfos {
     if layerInfo.sublayerIDs.count == 0 {
         // Get the url for the layer.
         let layerUrl = "\(mapServiceInfo?.url?.absoluteString ?? "")/\(UInt(layerInfo.id))"
         // add the name of layers which we want to hide from map in visibleLayers array
         if layersHidden.contains(layerUrl) {
              visibleLayers.append(layerInfo.name)
         }
     }
}
```

The hide layers like this

for i in 0...((dynamicMapServiceLayer?.mapImageSublayers.count)!-1) {
                        let layer = dynamicMapServiceLayer?.mapImageSublayers[i] as! AGSArcGISMapImageSublayer

```
for subLayer in layer.subLayerContents {
    if visibleLayers.contains(subLayer.name) {
         subLayer.isVisible = false
    }
    else {
      subLayer.isVisible = true
    }
   }
 }
```